# MongoDB Malformed Geometry with geojson

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, mongoose, geojson

Using MongoDB v2.6.5

When I attempt to save a geojson document into the db I receive the following error:

```
name: 'MongoError',
  code: 16755,
  err: 'insertDocument :: caused by :: 16755 Can\'t extract geo keys from object, malformed geometry?: { _id: ObjectId(\'55271b90d075728028d4c9e1\'), ..., location: [ { _id: ObjectId(\'55271b90d075728028d4c9e3\'), loc: { type: "Point", coordinates: [ -105.01621, 39.57422 ] } } ] } ], status: [ "lead" ], created: new Date(1428626320406), lastName: "Doe", firstName: "John", __v: 0 }' }
```

I'm attempting to insert a Point into the table with a 2dsphere index, all managed through MongooseJS as shown below.

```
var GeoAddressSchema = new Schema({
    // Only holds points.
    loc: {
        type: { type: String },
        coordinates: []
    }
});


var Lead = new Schema({
    // Other fields  ...
    location: [GeoAddressSchema],
    // ...
});

LeadAddressSchema.index({ location: '2dsphere' });
```

The geojson that is being saved:

```
{ type: "Point", coordinates: [ -111.855211, 33.58513 ] }
```

The geojson is valid according to: http://geojsonlint.com/ if I wrap the fields in quotes, but I should not need to do that (and cannot for Mongo afaik).

Anyone have any idea why this would fail? It looks correct.

**Reference links**

MongoDB GeoJSON: http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/geojson/

MongoDB 2dSphere: http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/core/2dsphere/

Comment: The GeoJSON points in the error messages and posted in your question both index fine for me. What version of MongoDB are you using? Can you post a minimal example that fails for you?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First observation: you need not introduce the `loc` path in the location structure.

Further, you need not even define a separate schema for your `location` field in the `Lead` schema.

Try this:

```
var Lead = new Schema({
  // Other fields  ...
  location: {
    type: {
      type: 'String',
      default: 'Point'  // and optionally skip including `type: String` everywhere
    },
    coordinates: {
      type: [Number]
    }
  },
  // More fields ...
});

LeadAddressSchema.index({ location: '2dsphere' });
```

Another problem I faced was that the `2dsphere` index gets messed up, when figuring and testing out solutions. So try dropping the index, or even better the collection after you make structural changes to the schema.

```
> db.lead.drop();  // on the mongo console`
```

Comment: This was perfect. Thank you. It also simplified a lot of my code as well. I really appreciate it!

Comment: BTW - I also ran into the index issue you spoke of. I had to drop and then -readd it. That is what lead me to realizing my initial implementation was wrong. It worked locally. Then I pushed it to a CI environment and realized it was broken.

Comment: Can explain how to drop the index and how else to replace the index?

Comment: YOU SAVED MY LIFE, after 2 days trying, I read your answer that it's a good thing to drop the collection, and it was this my problem. thank you man